# movie15.sty \includemovie beamer: show the movie at the same time as an item in an item list

Tags: beamer, lists, itemize, movie15

Please someone help. I spent 2 days on this problem: I am trying to show the movie at the same time as an item in an item list. How can I show the movie with the first item?

If I had an image instead of a movie I would write it like this:

```
\includegraphics<1>[width=\textwidth]{img1.jpg}
```

But for a movie it is not working. It shows the movie after all the items in the list are shown.

```
\includemovie<1>[poster]{3.25cm}{3.25cm}{movie1.jpg}
```

This doesn't work neither:

```
\visible<2->{\includemovie[poster]{3.25cm}{3.25cm}{movie1.jpg}}
```

Full working code snipet (if you have the images in your working directory):

```
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Overlay Specification}
\begin{columns}
\begin{column}{5cm}
\begin{itemize}
\item<1-> Figure 1
\item<2-> Figure 2
\item<3-> Figure 3
\end{itemize}
\vspace{3cm}
\end{column}
\begin{column}{5cm}
\includegraphics<1>[width=\textwidth]{img1.jpg}
\includegraphics<2>[width=\textwidth]{img2.jpg}
\includegraphics<3>[width=\textwidth]{img3.jpg}
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
```

But now I replace the first figure with a movie and it is not working anymore?

```
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Overlay Specification}
\begin{columns}
\begin{column}{5cm}
\begin{itemize}
\item<1-> Figure 1
\item<2-> Figure 2
\item<3-> Figure 3
\end{itemize}
\vspace{3cm}
\end{column}
\begin{column}{5cm}
\leavevmode
\visible<2->{\includemovie[poster]{3.25cm}{3.25cm}{images/predoc_oral/bullet_lg.mpg}}
\includegraphics<2>[width=\textwidth]{img2.jpg}
\includegraphics<3>[width=\textwidth]{img3.jpg}
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
```

(I posted the same question [here](http://makarandtapaswi.wordpress.com/2009/07/10/movie-package-movie15/#comment-125) but the webpage couldn't print the chevrons character, making my question not understandable.)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1192/how-do-i-mark-code-blocks). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it). I also removed the Markdown title formatting in order to make the question more readable, hope it's ok. `:)`

Comment: You replaced `\includegraphics<1>{...}` by `\visible<2->{\includemovie...}`. Shouldn't it be rather replaced by `\visible<1>{\includemovie...}`

Comment: Thanks @PauloCereda!  
Looks much better like this...    

Yes my bad @Alexander, I made a mistake when I copy-pasted...  
I meant:  
`\visible<1>{\includemovie...}`    

But event this doesn't work ...    

Any ideas?    

Oh... and this should be included in order for the file to work:  
    `\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}`    
    `\usepackage{graphicx}`  
    `\usepackage{movie15}`  
    `\begin{document}`  
    `... MORE CODE (from above...)`  
    `\end{document}`

BTW I can't figure out how to put linebreaks in this comment... sorry about that...

Comment: It is not a good idea to place images into `figure` environments in a presentation. This creates floating objects whose final placement is hard to predict.

Comment: Ah I didn't know that... but the thing is I will probably add captions later to my code, so that's why I need the: 
    `\begin{figure}[hpb!]`
    `\end{figure}`

Comment: As for captions, I'd rather put them along with `\includegraphics` into a `\parbox` for each figure.

Comment: @AlexanderGrahn: as far as I know, Beamer redefines the figure and table environments so they no longer float.  "The placement specification is ignored, and the figure or table is inserted immediately where the environment starts" (from the beamer manual).  That way you can use the same code in both your paper and your presentation.

Comment: We'd like to keep answers separate from questions, so you should write a separate answer instead of editing your answer into the question. Self-answers are perfectly admissible, and a well-written answer may earn you additional reputation.

Answer (score 1):

A community wiki answer, originally edited by the OP into his question: here's a working piece of code to show how to get it done. Not the way originally wanted, but at least the video is displayed on the slide as desired.

The first slide is the fail, and the second slide is the good one.
There may be a more elegant solution to this, so feel free to comment or to add another answer.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{movie15}
\def\hilite<#1>{\temporal<#1>{\color{gray}}{\color{blue}}{\color{blue!25}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}       
    \begin{columns}
\column{.5\textwidth} \hspace{0.001cm}
\begin{itemize}
\hilite<2> \item Line 1
\hilite<3> \item Line 2
\hilite<4> \item Line 3 
\end{itemize}

\column{.5\textwidth} \hspace{-20pt}
\begin{figure}[hpt!]
\visible<2->{
\includemovie[poster,autoplay]{3.25cm}{3.25cm}{images/predoc_oral/bullet_lg.mpg}}                                   
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[hpb!]
\includegraphics<3->[width=\textwidth]{images/predoc/WMAP_pie.png}
\end{figure}
\end{columns}       
\end{frame}


\begin{frame}       
    \begin{columns}
\column{.5\textwidth} \hspace{0.001cm}
\begin{itemize}
\hilite<2> \item Line 1
\end{itemize}

\column{.5\textwidth}
\vspace{-20pt}
\begin{figure}[hpt!]
\visible<2->{\includemovie[poster,autoplay]{3.25cm}{3.25cm}{%
        images/predoc_oral/bullet_lg.mpg}}                              
\end{figure}                            
\end{columns}

    \begin{columns}
\column{.5\textwidth} \hspace{0.001cm}
    \begin{itemize}
\hilite<3> \item Line 2
\hilite<4> \item Line 3 
\end{itemize}

\column{.5\textwidth}
    \vspace{20pt}                       
\begin{figure}[hpb!]
    \visible<3->{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{images/predoc/WMAP_pie.png}}
\end{figure}
\end{columns}       
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```