# Using \visible with media9 embedded videos

Tags: beamer, overlays, media9

I am currently switching to media9 to include video in beamer. I bump into an issue with the visibility option. I want to put two videos on a frame alongside with the list. The first one starts when the page opens along with some items while the second video to show and start when I highlight the second part of the items. Here is my code in hope for a solution:

```
\begin{frame}{Frame example}
    \begin{columns}
        \begin{column}{5.5cm}
            \begin{itemize}
                \item Blabla
                \item Blabla
                \item<2-> Bloblo
                \item<2-> Bloblo
            \end{itemize}
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}{4.5cm}
            \begin{figure}{
                \includemedia[
                    width=\columnwidth,height=2.8125cm,
                    activate=pageopen,
                    addresource=blabla_video.mp4,
                    flashvars={
                    source=blabla_video.mp4
                    &loop=true
                    &autoPlay=true
                    &scaleMode=letterbox
                    }
                    ]{}{VPlayer.swf}
                \caption{Blabla}}
            \end{figure}
            \visible<2->{
            \begin{figure}{         
                \includemedia[
                    width=\columnwidth,height=2.8125cm,
                    activate=pagevisible,
                    addresource=bloblo_video.mp4,
                    flashvars={
                    source=bloblo_video.mp4
                    &autoPlay=true
                    &loop=true
                    &scaleMode=letterbox
                    },
                    transparent
                    ]{}{VPlayer.swf}
                \caption{Bloblo}}
            \end{figure}}
        \end{column}
    \end{columns}
\end{frame}
```

Also I notice that Adobe Reader is considerably much slower reading video with media9 than with movie15. Is it just related to my configuration or there is something I am missing like a codec of some sort? Is it related to the fact that a warning concerning a signature field detected appears?

I am running MikTex 2.9, compiling with pdflatex and opening the pdf with Adobe Reader 11.0.3

I hope you guys have an answer...

Comment: It might be related to http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/45633/25305. I will try it tomorrow...

Comment: I took the liberty to adjust the title a little, if you don't mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`media9` is not well suited for use with Beamer overlays. The latters produce multiple PDF pages per frame and possibly re-insert the video.

In particular, `\visible` reserves space on those overlays where its content is not displayed. For getting the dimension of the required white-space, the argument of `\visible` is typeset into some box for measuring. Media files are displayed within so-called PDF annotations, which do not belong to the page content but live in a separate layer above the page. They are inevitably added to the page resources and hence will be shown even in overlays where they are supposed to be invisible.

There is one trick to make it work though. Within the `\visible` argument, we place a `\rule` box with the same dimensions as the video and let this one be used in overlays where the video should be hidden:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{media9}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Frame example}
  \begin{columns}
    \begin{column}{5.5cm}
      \begin{itemize}
        \item Blabla
        \item Blabla
        \item<2-> Bloblo
        \item<2-> Bloblo
      \end{itemize}
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{4.5cm}
      \begin{figure}
        \includemedia[
          width=\columnwidth,height=2.8125cm,
          activate=pageopen,
          addresource=blabla.mp4,
          flashvars={
            source=blabla.mp4
            &loop=true
            &autoPlay=true
            &scaleMode=letterbox
          }
        ]{}{VPlayer.swf}
        \caption{Blabla}
      \end{figure}
      \visible<2->{
      \begin{figure}
        \only<1>{\rule{\columnwidth}{2.8125cm}}%
        \only<2->{%
          \includemedia[
            width=\columnwidth,height=2.8125cm,
            activate=pagevisible,
            addresource=bloblo.mp4,
            flashvars={
              source=bloblo.mp4
              &autoPlay=true
              &loop=true
              &scaleMode=letterbox
            }
          ]{}{VPlayer.swf}%
        }  
        \caption{Bloblo}
      \end{figure}}
    \end{column}
  \end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Note that, when passing to the second overlay, the first video is again extracted from the PDF, unpacked, loaded and started, which may lead to some latency. This cannot be avoided. With `movie15` it was possible to 'pull' the playing video from one page to the next using JavaScript. This was quite hackish, but worked somehow. With `media9` this possibility has gone.

Comment: Thanks! It works even if I will have to change my slide as I want the first video to continue playing...

Any hint about the latency I observed when it comes to load and play the video?

Comment: @TazgerO: Yes but be aware that it starts from zero, not where you have left it on the first overlay.

Comment: I will keep that in mind but I was thinking about just avoiding the overlay

Comment: @TazgerO: As I said before, media files and VPlayer.swf are compressed objects within the PDF. They must be extracted, decompressed, loaded into FlashPlayer plugin and initialized therein before being played back. This takes some time

Comment: I just happen to use your trick... Thank again...

Comment: @TazgerO: You are welcome.

Comment: Does the file size have a huge influence on the loading time? I mean the package is sizing to the video to fit the dimension set in Beamer. If one set the video already to the proper dimension does it help?

Comment: @TazgerO: It is the file size that influences loading time. Of course, it depends on both, length (time) and dimension (width times height). There is a FlashVar setting that avoids pixel interpolation as it suppresses rescaling the video dimensions to the actual display size on the screen: `scaleMode=none`. But this rescaling has a negligible impact on playback latency because it is delegated to the GPU.

Comment: @TazgerO: BTW it is difficult to set the dimensions in the PDF to the actual video dimensions because one needs to know the resolution of the target display (projector, monitor). However, one can have the video play in a floating window (see option `windowed`) It can be given the correct size in pixels.

Comment: @TazgerO: To avoid embedding the video file into the PDF, but play it from the hard disk, see [this discussion](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/72993). This avoids extraction and decompression of the media file and reduces loading time.